# How to reliably run ksql command in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-cloud

Using Confluent Kafka Cloud API endpoint I send HTTP request containing `CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM` command that is used to update already existent stream. Half of the times, however ksqldb returns 502 Error:

```
Could not write the statement 'CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM...

Caused by: Another command with the same id
```

It seems this is a well known issue happening when ksqlDB command fails to commit. It has been "recommended" to send the same command again and again "...as a subsequent retry of the command should work fine".

Another suggestion is to "to clean up the command from the futures map on a commit failure".

Here is a GitHub issue link: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/6340

The first recommendation that talks about re-sending the same command multiple times in a row to finally make it work, does not seem to be a good solution. I wonder if the second recommendation to clean up the command from the future map is a better choice?

How do we clean up the command from the future map? Is there any other solution known to make ksqldb reliably execute the ksql command?

Comment: The "futures map" is internal to the server.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there are many options to get around it then

Comment: For anyone coming to this question, someone wrote a Gradle plugin to manage KSQL scripts and pipelines. https://www.confluent.io/blog/deploying-kafka-streams-and-ksql-with-gradle-part-2-managing-ksql-implementations/